# How do I make pratilk pages with ngTemplate and ngContainer

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular8

for example:

```sh
├── modal
│   ├── layer
│   └──── layer.component.html
│   └──── layer.component.ts
│   │
│   ├── warningModal
│   └──── warningModal.component.html
│   └──── warningModal.component.ts
└
```

My goal is to create a modal structure with layer. And using this modal is to create only the inside of the warning modal.

layel.component.html

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="control"></ng-container>
```

warningModal.component.ts

```
<ng-template #control>
  <p>hello guys</p>
</ng-template>
```

why not work? If I wrote it in a single file, it would work. But it doesn't work when you write to different components. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you write both in single line at that time template needed for `ngTemplateOutlet` is present at same place so it works

2) When these are in two different component there is no relation between each other So when passing `ngTemplateOutlet="options"` it just assumes it as string not a template reference variable so nothing display

Use this method

**warningModal.component.html**
│

```
<app-layer [temp]="control"></app-layer>
<ng-template #control>
  <p>hello guys</p>
</ng-template>
```

**layer.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layer',
  templateUrl: './layer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layer.component.css']
})
export class LayerComponent{
  @Input() temp
}
```

**layer.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="temp"></ng-container>
```

Working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzlyhq?embed=1&file=src/app/layer/layer.component.html